# Can we do show less and show more in the All-day event in Week View Or react-big-calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-big-calendar

Following are the two images i am being trying to implement

[image: Can this functionality be added in all day event in week view?]

[image: after clicking on 2 more it should expand]

Is there anything been implemented in react-big-calendar to help me with this

Answer (score 0):

There's a very hacky way of doing this I've found in an existing project I'm currently working on.

[image: Show more button]

Basically:

- reduce the events (for week view only) by dateTime.
- override `eventWrapper` to add the "Show More" widget

Here are example code snippets:

```
const eventList =
  view === Views.MONTH
    ? mapEventsForBigCalendar(scheduledPosts, timeZone)
    : weekEventsReducer(scheduledPosts, timeZone);

return (
  <BigCalendar
    events={eventList}
    components={{
      components={{
      eventWrapper: CalendarEvent, // The event plus the Show More widget
      week: {
        event: WeekEvent,
      },
      month: {
        event: MonthEvent,
      },
    }}
  ...
  />
)
```

The reduce function basically discards events in the same date/time.

```
function mapEventForBigCalendar(timezone: TimeZone) {
  return (event: ScheduledPost) => ({
    id: event.id,
    start: changeTimeZone(event.startTime, timezone),
    end: changeTimeZone(event.endTime, timezone),
    resource: {
      post: event.post,
      sameDateTimeEvents: [], // needed to add Show More functionality to week view. Big Calendar doesn't support that out of the box
    },
  });
}

export function mapEventsForBigCalendar(events: ScheduledPost[] = [], timezone: TimeZone): BigCalendarEvent[] {
  return events.map(mapEventForBigCalendar(timezone));
}

export function weekEventsReducer(events: ScheduledPost[] = [], timezone: TimeZone): BigCalendarEvent[] {
  const emptyMap = new Map<string, BigCalendarEvent>();
  const map = mapEventForBigCalendar(timezone);

  const eventsByDateTime = events.reduce((slotEvents, anotherEvent: ScheduledPost) => {
    const groupKey = format(anotherEvent.startTime, 'M-d-hh-a');
    const existingEvent = slotEvents.get(groupKey);

    if (existingEvent) {
      existingEvent.resource.sameDateTimeEvents.push(map(anotherEvent));
      slotEvents.set(groupKey, existingEvent);
    } else {
      slotEvents.set(groupKey, map(anotherEvent));
    }

    return slotEvents;
  }, emptyMap);

  return Array.from(eventsByDateTime.values());
}
```

And now you have grouped the events (actually discarded some and adding a counter to main events) you can render them as you want. You'll be using the same JSX code you used inside `WeekEvent` component, but this time that will be wrapped inside a container that also appends the "Show More" widget.

```
const CalendarEvent = ({ children, style, type, event: calendarEvent }) => {
  const isMonthView = type === 'date';
  if (isMonthView) return children;

  const mediaCount = calendarEvent.resource.post?.mediaCount();

  const sameDateTimeEventsCount = calendarEvent.resource.sameDateTimeEvents.length ?? 0;

  const ShowMore = (
    <button
      key={`${calendarEvent.id}-see-more`}
      className="rbc-button-link rbc-show-more"
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // onShowMore(e, calendarEvent); // You can pass this callback by currying the eventWrapper component
      }}>
      <Typography component="span" whiteSpace="nowrap" variant="subtitle2" fontWeight={600}>
        {`+ ${sameDateTimeEventsCount}`}
      </Typography>
      <Typography component="span" variant="subtitle2" fontWeight={600}>
        MORE
      </Typography>
    </button>
  );

  return (
    <div className="rbc-event" style={style}>
      <div className="rbc-event-week">
        {/* <div className="rbc-event-label">...</div> */}
        <div className="rbc-event-content">
          <EventPill mediaCount={mediaCount} event={calendarEvent} />
        </div>
      </div>
      {sameDateTimeEventsCount && ShowMore}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Let me show you the missing part of "currying" the eventWrapper so you can provide a callback. You just need a good old HOC.

```
const WithCallback = ({ onShowMore }: WithCallbackProps) => {
  const CalendarEvent = ({ children, type, event: calendarEvent }) => {
  ...
  return CalendarEvent;
};

export default WithCallback;
```

And then use it like:

```
eventWrapper: CalendarEvent({
  onShowMore: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>, calendarEvent: BigCalendarEvent) => {
    setShowMorePopupPosition({ left: e.clientX - 95, top: e.clientY });

    // whatever state handler you are using to populate the popup
    onShowMore(calendarEvent.resource.sameDateTimeEvents, calendarEvent.start);
  },
}),
```

[image: Show more popup]

Answer (score -1):

React-Big-Calendar handles this via a popup, instead of inline. They [have an example](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#popup) in their documentation.

Comment: Broken link. Also, Show More functionality is currently only available for Month view, not Week view. You can try it out here: https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/props--on-show-more